# How to return in order? Like first return a then b

Tags: python, function, generator

So lets say, we have a function which is like this:

```
def function():
   k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   
   a=length(k)

   b=24
   c=90
   return a,b,c
```

The output i want is something like this:
9
24
90

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Use `len` instead of `length`. The rest is ok.

Comment: It works fine for me (If I change length(k) to len(k)). What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting space separated output of numbers, you can use this.

```
def function():
  k=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   
  a=len(k)

  b=24
  c=90
  return '{} {} {}'.format(a,b,c)

function()
```

you also have to change `length() to len()`.